# How to change icon image of button on mouse entered/mouse exit?

Tags: java, swing, icons, jbutton, mouselistener

I want to change icon image of an Button on Mouse Entered and Mouse Exited.

```
    private void jButton1MouseEntered(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {    
    this.jButton1.setBackground(Color.red);
    this.jButton1.setForeground(Color.BLUE)
    }  ;
 private void jButton1MouseExited(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {                                     
       this.jButton1.setBackground(Color.lightGray);
       this.jButton1.setForeground(Color.BLACK);

    }
```

Please suggest how  to change icon image.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

See [`setRolloverIcon(Icon)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/AbstractButton.html#setRolloverIcon%28javax.swing.Icon%29) (no need for the `MouseListener`).